# What is the difference between 'out' keyword and ':'?

Tags: kotlin, generics

What is the difference between

```
private fun foo(list: ArrayList<out Number>) {}
```

and

```
private fun <T : Number> foo(list: ArrayList<T>)
```

?

Answer (score 6):

To the calling code, the constraint on what argument can be passed is very similar, but the first one is slightly more lenient because it is declaring that it won't need to feed the List (adding to it). For example, you can pass an `ArrayList<Int>` to either of these, but you cannot pass an `ArrayList<out Int>` to the second one.

To the code inside the function, with the first one you cannot add anything to the list since it has the `out` constraint. With the second one, you theoretically could add to it, but only if you have a `T` available to add to it. Since `T` is part of the function signature, the only way to have a `T` available is to retrieve it from the ArrayList inside this function, or to add another function parameter of type `T`.

Comment: In this case, which option is better to use?

Comment: It 100% depends on what you’re trying to achieve. I described the difference in what they enable/limit.